# @typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions' was not found

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jasmine, eslint, tslint

I want to use Jasmine and i'm in the middle of the tutorial of Jasmine, but they don't mention in the document how to fix the error "Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions' was not found.eslint(@typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions)"

the error occurs in the file enzyme.ts:

```
import { configure } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import jasmineEnzyme from "jasmine-enzyme";

configure({ adapter:  new Adapter() });

// tslint:disable-next-line: only-arrow-functions
beforeEach(function() {
  jasmineEnzyme();
});
```

this is the link to the tutorial for Jasmine:

https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/react_with_npm

Comment: Pretty sure that this is not a problem connected to jasmine but to eslint.
Do you have a .eslintrc.js file in your project? What is the content of this file?

Comment: yes i have replaced eslint with tslint

Answer (score 1):

That typescript-eslint rule [does exist per the docs](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/3e06f0f0211549d7e5da5dfe73fbb521650ffc5d/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-unused-expressions.md). A couple of possibilities here:

- Your project isn't properly including the typescript-eslint rules, per https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/docs/getting-started/linting/README.md
- You're using a very old version of typescript-eslint (the rule was [added](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/commits/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-unused-expressions.md) in November 2019)